# UITextField won't return and text field can't be changed. How do I fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am having problems trying to get the keyboard to go to the next field or return when the return key is pressed, my code is:

```
@interface LoginViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.userField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)tapLogin:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"login");
}


#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate methods

// for return and next
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
if (textField == self.userField) {

    [self.passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if (textField == self.passwordField) {

    [self tapLogin:nil];
}
return YES;
}
```

The cursor beings in the userField but hitting the return key does nothing, if I manually tap on another field i.e the password one this also won't do anything. The cursor is stuck in the username field. I have implemented the  protocol in my header file and also set the text fields as delegates in the interface builder. Could someone help please?

Comment: Is Delegate methods call when return key Pressed?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: my Question : Is textFieldShouldReturn method call, when return key press on keyboard.

Comment: no it's not being called, I don't understand why

Comment: Please add these 2 lines in viewDidLoad Method
`self.userField.delegate=self;
self.passwordField.delegate=self;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Remove `[self.userField becomeFirstResponder];` method from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` ie, remove the below method

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.userField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

and add

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.userField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```